# footer text and page numbers in itextsharp

Tags: c#, itext, pdfptable

I have a PDF document where, usually, each page is stamped with a footer with a page number preceded by the name of the chapter or section that the page should be in. However, occasionally, I get some large table results that span over a number of pages.

I need to maintain the footer stamp for the current section they are in but because of the large tables running over a number of pages, those pages are getting stamped with the previous sections footer stamp and the last page that the table is displayed on gets the current sections footer stamp.

If anyone can come up with a solution towards setting and maintaining a chapter/section footer stamp for the current section that would be great.

*** Additional *** 
Here is the code for the onEndPage overide.

```
public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
{
    base.OnEndPage(writer, document);

    if ((pagenumber - 1) >= 1)
    {
        String text = footer + pagenumber.ToString();
        float len = bf.GetWidthPoint(text, 8);

        Rectangle pageSize = document.PageSize;

        cb.SetRGBColorFill(100, 100, 100);

        cb.BeginText();
        cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 8);
        cb.SetTextMatrix(pageSize.GetRight(100), pageSize.GetBottom(20));
        cb.ShowText(text);
        cb.EndText();
        if (this.currentChapter > this.totalChapters)
        {
            pagenumber = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            pagenumber++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        pagenumber++;
    }
}
```

I skip adding the header and footer information for the document because I have a cover page. Because the various parts are disparate information, I have broken them down into chapters and subsections based on the various areas. Also, the users have the option of printing out a number of PDF's at once generated from database information. And at the start of each chapter, I set the footer text using the following command:

```
this.PageEventHandler.footer = "(Part 1) - Page: ";
```

Or at least I am trying to. When it comes to doing the second section (Employment History), if a person has been swapped around various departments a lot in their employment history they can build up quite a record and it overflows onto several pages.

Comment: How are you stamping the header and footer? Are you using page events?

Comment: Bruno, I am using an extension to the pdfPageEventHelper object yes. Normally it, as I said, stamps the footer to the page on the onEndPage event correctly, but if the table overflows onto a new page, the onEndPage doesnt seem to get called and it continues to use the previous sections footer text.

Comment: That's not normal behavior. How are you adding the footer? Please show us some code: we can't fix what we can't reproduce. Also: which version of iTextSharp are you using?

Comment: I am using the latest version (5.3.3)

Comment: So you're not using the onChapter() event to change the footer? That's the best way to control what happens, because I'm not sure what you mean when you say: "at the start of each chapter, I set the footer text". You can create all the chapters you want; what matters is when you add them. Finally: why are you using Chapter and Section? Using PdfOutline is much more reliable.

Comment: I inherited this project from someone else who originally wrote it in 3.1.5.0 and in C# 2.0 and I am updating it to more modern versions. I am basically learning on the fly. I am learning from trying to translate the Java chapter examples into C# as I fly and from what I can gleam from around the web.

Comment: Did it work in 3.1.5.0? Regression would surprise me, although Chapter and Section are considered somewhat obsolete. I don't think we're actively testing this on Jenkins.

Comment: Ok, diligent use of the onChapter and onEndChapter overrides seems to fix that, however, if the table spans 3 pages... the middle page gets nothing... thoughts Bruno?

Comment: The previous version was using HeaderFooter for the header and footer stuff and when I upgraded to 5.3.3.0, it just broke everything to do with headers and footers.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is to use `PdfPageEvents` to add the footer as each page as it's processed. The documentation is for the Java version, but you need to override the `onEndPage` method.

[iTextPDF - PdfPageEvent](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0419__PDF/PdfPageEventHelper.htm)

Comment: Hi Echilon,I do override the onEndPage event, but it doesnt seem to pick up the page breaks caused by a PdfPTable overflowing onto a new page. Or rather it does, but it doesnt seem to want to add in the correct footer text.